# Conda check if environment could be created on a new machine

Tags: python, environment, conda

I am sharing my python environment with conda and a exported environment.yml using the command.

```
conda env export > environment.yml
```

Now I want to make sure, that this environment could be created on another machine which has not downloaded any of the packages in the environment.yml before.

Is this possible with anaconda?

The problem I'm facing is, that my colleague had problems creating the environment with `conda env create --file environment.yml` because some of the packages couldn't be found with that specific versions. I can't reproduce the error because the packages are already downloaded and I don't want to delete them and risk facing the same problems.

Comment: a `conda` environment can be created from a yaml file with `conda env create --file environment.yml`. did you and your colleague try that?

Comment: yes, I added it to the question.

Comment: can you post more information about the issue? your operating system info and your colleague's, and the trace of your colleague's error.